# Multiple swt buttons, same listener

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have an application which I want to develop in SWT, and I was wondering if there is a possibility to use a single Selection Listener for multiple buttons. For example I have a menu bar which contains an "open" menu item, and I also have a toolbar where I have an open button, can I use the same listener for both? I would be glad to see just a simple example if there is a possibility, and an explanation if there is no possibility to do what's above.

Comment: Why haven't you tried it yourself?

Comment: Define the listener as a variable, the use it for all buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Baz for adding the above question, and for help, it works :)

Comment: @Baz I have tried several listeners of SWT buttons. When using a single listener for multiple buttons how can you understand from which button the event comes from? Didn't get any parameter in listener method which indicates this info.

Comment: @iamcrypticcoder You can use `e.widget` to get the source button like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24949328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's possible ... your listener will have to check the event's source attribute to determine where the event was fired from.

If you're attaching the listener to different object's, you probably want to implement a generic [Listener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#addListener(int,%20org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener)) instead of an object specific listener.